# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined at event.js:65

Tags: node.js, http

I was trying to run a basic http server on node js. I was trying to run the below code copied from some online source.

```
var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');
    response.write('hello client!');
    response.end();
});
    server.listen(8080);
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

event.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined at event.js:65 at HTMLDocument. (event.js:66) at c (jquery.js:4) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:4) at ready (jquery.js:4) (anonymous) @ event.js:65 (anonymous) @ event.js:66 c @ jquery.js:4 fireWith @ jquery.js:4 ready @ jquery.js:4 setTimeout (async) x.ready.promise @ jquery.js:4 ready @ jquery.js:4 init @ jquery.js:4 x @ jquery.js:4 (anonymous) @ jquery.js:4 (anonymous) @ jquery.js:5 (anonymous) @ jquery.js:6

I dont understand why I am getting this error. Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Its working fine. i checked.

Comment: event.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at event.js:65
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (event.js:66)
    at c (jquery.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:4)
    at ready (jquery.js:4)
(anonymous) @ event.js:65
(anonymous) @ event.js:66
c @ jquery.js:4
fireWith @ jquery.js:4
ready @ jquery.js:4
setTimeout (async)
x.ready.promise @ jquery.js:4
ready @ jquery.js:4
init @ jquery.js:4
x @ jquery.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:5
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:6

Comment: I do get the correct message of ''hello client!" in the browser, and 'request starting...' in the node command line, but I also get the above error in the browser console

Comment: The code you post have nothing to do with the client side error you get. Show us your relevant client side code.